# JavaScript, post, button will not give server response until the second click

Tags: javascript, post, addeventlistener, preventdefault

I have a script that is scanning a page for all buttons and logging the click of each into the database. Unfortunately the button data will not submit until the second click  am I using the addEventListener and removeEvent listener in the correct location?

```
var trkButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < trkButtons.length; ++i) {

    //submit button
    if (trkButtons[i].getAttribute("type") == "submit") {
        trkButtons[i].addEventListener("click", addBtnClickListener, false);
    }

    //image button
    if (trkButtons[i].getAttribute("type") == "image") {
        trkButtons[i].addEventListener("click", addBtnClickListener, false);
    }

    //file upload
    if (trkButtons[i].getAttribute("type") == "file") {
        trkButtons[i].addEventListener("click", addBtnClickListener, false);
    }
    else { }
}

function addBtnClickListener(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.click();
    this.removeEventListener('click', addBtnClickListener, false);

    var eventType = "button.click";
    var ctrBtnText = this.value;
    track(this, eventType, '', '', ctrBtnText, '', '', '');

}
```

Comment: Why are you revoming the event listener? Why are you triggering a new click event? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am logging the click in a database, I need to remove it and trigger it again to stop the click from hitting the server side before it can be logged. Its for tracking purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here is what your `addBtnClickListener` function does:

1. Prevents default action to run (form submission, file upload window opening)
2. Run this function one more time
3. Remove this event listener from the clicked element
4. Log stuff

Form submission works the second time because first time, at step 3 you remove this event handler which actually prevents form submission.
If you don't wanna prevent default behavior like form submitting, file upload dialog opening, etc. then you should not use `e.preventDefault()`.

**Possible solution:**

```
function addBtnClickListener(e) {
    // the code below will be executed, before the form is submitted
    // no need for other action if this is all we do
    var eventType = "button.click";
    var ctrBtnText = this.value;
    track(this, eventType, '', '', ctrBtnText, '', '', '');
}
```

**Reason to use preventDefault:**

```
function validateForm(e) {
    var data = document.getElementById('someData').value;
    if (isValid(data) === false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // ask user to correct invalid data here
    }
}
```

***Note:*** you can submit forms manually with `this.form.submit()` but this is usually not needed as the default action does this for us.

Comment: It works in most cases except Chrome, the form is submitted before the click event can be tracked.

Comment: Sound very interesting. I set up a little testing fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xdsHc/).  
For me both events are working in Chrome, every action happens before the form is submitted. Have you tried the form submit event, instead of the submit button click event?